# opening of hedging position using pinescript

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

i am finding that the instrument that i trade in (nifty options and bank nifty options) provide huge swings at specific times on a regular basis (say at 1200 IST, 1500 IST, and 1345 IST), mostly corresponding to opening of London and NASDAQ.

i want to open a hedged position at these time period (ie 1 short and 1 long) with a very small stop-loss (say 2 points/approx 40 tics) and exit with target of 25-30 points(500-600 ticks)

is there anyway to code the simultaneous opening of long and short position without one cancelling the other so that the movement can be captured in trade?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hedging is not available. Neither opening orders in another symbol nor taking contrary positions in the same symbol. You would need to run two instances of the same script which are operating in opposite directions and examine the outcome of two strategies. Best available option.

Comment: thank you for the quick response. will try to do some work around